# Is it possible to install SonarQube 4.5 locally to be able to analyzie my maven project?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

i am discovering sonarqube 4.5 and my first documentation walkthrough left me with a basic question : is it possible to install sonarqube 4.5 locally to perform the needed analysis on my local project? i mean the documentation suggests the following :

The Database and the Analyzers must be located in the same network.

The Database and the Analyzers must not be installed on the same machine.

This led me to the obvious conclusion that i need at least 2 machines to perform a full analysis to my maven project. So how is it possible for the average joe who has only one machine to be able to test SonarQube on a local project ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run Sonar on a single machine. For a production setup, it's recommended to have dedicated DB, but for test purposes, you can use built-in DB.

Follow these instructions: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You will find a series of posts on my blog describing precisely all the different steps to install SonarQube with Jenkins an a laptop: http://qualilogy.com/en/category/sonar/sonar-installation/

Regards.